# PHP equivalent of PyQuery or Nokogiri?

Tags: php, screen-scraping

Basically, I want to do some HTML screen scraping, but figuring out if it is possible in PHP.

In Python, I would use
[PyQuery](http://pyquery.org/).
In Ruby, I would use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Answer (score 8):

In PHP you can use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

P.S. it's kinda ironic, I came to this page looking for phpQuery equivalent in Python :)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP for screen scraping you can use Snoopy (http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/) or Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a PHP port of Ruby nokogiri](https://github.com/b1rdex/php-nokogiri)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to Nokogiri in PHP is [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/).

Answer (score 0):

There are also the built in [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) libraries.  They include DomDocument with its [loadHTML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method for parsing html from a string and [DomElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) and [DomNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) for building up HTML via an object.