# Convert CSS selector to XPath in Python

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors

Is there a Python library that can parse an CSS selector and emit an equivalent XPath expression? For Ruby, there is [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/CSS.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently took over cssselect and made it an independent project after extracting it from lxml: http://packages.python.org/cssselect/

It does precisely what the question asks for. The XPath expressions produced can then be used in lxml. PyQuery actually uses cssselect (formerly lxml.cssselect)

Comment: Wow, nice, thanks for the follow-up. So [`lxml.cssselect.css_to_xpath`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.cssselect-module.html#css_to_xpath) is obsolete? Was it ever an official feature? Nice work indeed.

Comment: @NiklasB. it was an implementation detail and will go away with lxml 2.4 (not released yet) when `lxml.cssselect` becomes a thin wrapper around `cssselect`. The `CSSSelector` class and `HtmlElement.cssselect` method remain for compatibility

Comment: I really wish lxml updated their docs often enough to mention that cssselect was taken out despite previously being packaged. but thanks

Comment: @Amalgovinus, file a bug?

Answer (score 4):

How about [pyQuery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery)?

Answer based on [PHP equivalent of PyQuery or Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815726/php-equivalent-of-pyquery-or-nokogiri)

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question, and the documentation is not the best I've seen. Can you point me to the functionality that I am looking for? (Converting CSS to XPath, that is). **EDIT** found it! It's actually part of lxml though, but thanks for the hint.