# Extract content of meta element in php?

Tags: php

I am totally new to PHP development and I would like to extract the contents of a meta tag.

I have this code that allows me to extract the contents of the element # squad.

```
// Pull in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser
include("simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");

// Settings on top
$sitesToCheck = array(
                    // id is the page ID for selector
                    array("url" => "http://www.arsenal.com/first-team/players", "selector" => "#squad"),
                    array("url" => "http://www.liverpoolfc.tv/news", "selector" => "ul[style='height:400px;']")
                );
$savePath = "cachedPages/";
$emailContent = "";

// For every page to check...
foreach($sitesToCheck as $site) {
    $url = $site["url"];

    // Calculate the cachedPage name, set oldContent = "";
    $fileName = md5($url);
    $oldContent = "";

    // Get the URL's current page content
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    // Find content by querying with a selector, just like a selector engine!
    foreach($html->find($site["selector"]) as $element) {
        $currentContent = $element->plaintext;;
    }

    // If a cached file exists
    if(file_exists($savePath.$fileName)) {
        // Retrieve the old content
        $oldContent = file_get_contents($savePath.$fileName);
    }

    // If different, notify!
    if($oldContent && $currentContent != $oldContent) {


        // Build simple email content
        $emailContent = "Hey, the following page has changed!\n\n".$url."\n\n";
    }

    // Save new content
    file_put_contents($savePath.$fileName,$currentContent);
}

// Send the email if there's content!
if($emailContent) {
    // Sendmail!
    mail("me@myself.name","Sites Have Changed!",$emailContent,"From: alerts@myself.name","\r\n");
    // Debug
    echo $emailContent;
}
```

But I want to change this code to get the number of comments in income.

Here is the meta tag where i would just extract the number of comments :

```
<meta item="desc" content="Comments:645">
```

Am I clear enough, do you understand me?

If I am not explicit enough, ask me?

Thanks for help

Comment: You are clearly using a library or other code of some kind. Could you clarify what it is? What code uses the `$sitesToCheck` variable?

Comment: That code doesn't "extract" anything, it's just an array. What are you doing with it afterwards? That's what any answer depends on.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming you want to parse out the value of the content attribute when supplied with a string like the above?

Comment: I've edited my post ! it's more clear now ?

Comment: What is `file_get_html`? It's not a standard PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to do this. You could either use the native PHP function: [`get_meta_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) like so:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://yoursite.com');
$comments = $tags['desc'];
```

Or you could use RegEx, but the above would be much more practical.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for might be screen scraping.

This is the process where a programming-language like php, python or ruby loads a website in memory and uses various selectors to grab content from it. 
Screen scraping is mostly used on websites that feature a lot of interesting data but have no json or xml API's

having googled around for it I stumbled on this post:
[PHP equivalent of PyQuery or Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815726/php-equivalent-of-pyquery-or-nokogiri)

This article explains more about screen-scraping for web:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Answer (score 0):

Look for use domDocument

```
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($htmlPage);
    $metas = $dom->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('meta');
    $ar = array();
    foreach ($metas as $meta) {
        $name = $meta->getAttribute('name');
        $value = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        $ar[$name] = $value;
    }
    print_r($ar); // print array meta-values
```

Comment: thanks, i've edited my post and my code ! Where put this code in my code